# How do I make `wait` return the error code if there is at least one completed process that errored?

Tags: bash

Here's what I have so far

```bash
(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; false) &
(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; true) &
wait
echo $? # this is showing `0` but I want it to be non-zero at this point
```

I also want to make sure that all processes finish so
chaining `(wait -n) && (wait -n) && (wait -n) && (wait -n) && (wait -n)` won't work because the `false` is in the middle

Comment: Put all the PIDs in an array. Then use `wait` in a loop, waiting for each PID, and checking its exit status.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I guess I had to track it by PID

```bash
# Initialize an array to store exit statuses
exit_statuses=()

(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; false) &
(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; true) &

# Store the process IDs (PIDs) in an array (corrected to use jobs and awk)
pids=($(jobs -l | awk '{ print $2 }'))

# Wait for all processes to finish and collect their exit statuses
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
    wait -n
    exit_statuses+=($?)
done

# Check if any process had a non-zero exit status
for status in "${exit_statuses[@]}"; do
    if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
        # At least one process had an error, so return a non-zero exit code
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

The key line that makes this work is which lists the active jobs and PIDs for the current bash session

```
pids=($(jobs -l | awk '{ print $2 }'))
```

I also verified that `jobs` does not list the parent processes by doing this

```
sleep 200 & bash -c "jobs -l"
```

which returns no results but

```
sleep 200 & jobs -l
```

on it's own does

Comment: Your `pids` is just the last background process. You need to add to the array after each process is started.

Comment: `pids=();  (sleep 1; true) & pids+=($!);  (sleep 1; true) & pids+=($!); ....`

Comment: yeah I forgot to put in the corrected version I noticed just now I pasted the wrong version.  The correction puts the pids as pids=($(jobs -l | awk '{ print $2 }')) which limits it to the current bash session as well.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano, since jobs are closely tied do the current process, the output of the `jobs` command is not reliable when run in a sub-process.  `pids=($(jobs -l | ...))` might not work in some situations.  The only reliable way that I know to use the output of the `jobs` command is to run it in the current shell with its output redirected to a file and read the required information from that file.

Answer (score 2):

You could wait for one process at a time with `wait -n` and check if it exits with non-zero to set the final verdict. I'm also adding `-p` to collect the process id in a variable for debugging purposes.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; false) &
(sleep 1; true) &
(sleep 1; true) &

failures=0

while true
do
    wait -np pid
    rv=$?

    if [[ $rv == 127 ]]
    then
        # no more processes to wait for
        break
    fi

    # count failing processes
    (( failures += rv != 0 ))

    echo DEBUG: $rv $pid
done

echo $failures # the number of failing processes
```

---

If you start more background processes and only want to wait for a certain set of them, you could put the process ids in an array and tell `wait` to just wait for those processes.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# declare an array to store process ids and add each pid to it
declare -a pids
(sleep 1; true) &
pids+=($!)
(sleep 1; true) &
pids+=($!)
(sleep 1; false) &
pids+=($!)
(sleep 1; true) &
pids+=($!)
(sleep 1; false) &
pids+=($!)

echo "waiting for ${pids[@]}"
failures=0

while [[ ${#pids[@]} -ne 0 ]]
do
    # only wait for the processes in the pids array
    wait -np pid ${pids[@]}
    rv=$?

    if [[ $rv == 127 ]]
    then
        # no more processes to wait for
        # (should not happen since the pids array is not empty)
        break
    fi

    # remove the collected pid from the array
    pids=( ${pids[@]/$pid/} )

    # count failing processes
    (( failures += rv != 0 ))

    echo DEBUG: $rv $pid
done

echo $failures
```

Comment: It's good but I chose a different answer because the pids+= is being plopped in between each step (which works mind you) but I'd rather keep it straight through so I used the `jobs` to get the active PIDs

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano You'd typically do the spawning in a loop and then there's only one `pids+=($!)`. Also, `jobs` will show you _all_ your processes and if that's what you're interested in, then you do not need the `pids` array at all and can just use the first of my two examples that does `wait -np pid`. Also, parsing `jobs -l` is error prone. You may not get a pid in the second column. The safe way is to use `$!`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do what you want is to abuse Bash's pipeline mechanisms.  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates the idea:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

(
    set -o pipefail

    exec 3<&0
    exec 4>&1

    (sleep 1; true)  <&3 >&4    |
    (sleep 1; true)  <&3 >&4    |
    (sleep 1; false) <&3 >&4    |
    (sleep 1; true)  <&3 >&4    |
    (sleep 1; true)  <&3 >&4

    status=$? pipestatus=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )

    declare -p status pipestatus
)
```

- The outer parentheses `(...)` create a subshell to ensure that the changes to shell options and file descriptors don't affect the top-level program.
- `set -o pipefail` causes a pipeline to return non-zero status if any of the processes in it returns non-zero status.
- `exec 3<&0` and `exec 4>&1` set up file descriptor 3 as an alias for the "real" standard input and file descriptor 4 as an alias for the "real" standard output.
- The redirections in `... | (sleep 1; true)  <&3 >&4 | ...` ensure that the process uses the "real" standard input and standard output instead of reading and writing pipes.  They are actually not needed in this example because `sleep` doesn't read standard input or write standard output, but they would be needed for other commands.  The effect of the redirections is that the pipes associated with the `|` symbols are not used for input or output.  Their only effect is to make `pipefail` and `PIPESTATUS` useful.
- `status=$? pipestatus=( "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" )` captures the overall status of the pipeline to `status` and the status of each of the processes in the pipeline to `pipestatus`.  See [PIPESTATUS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PIPESTATUS) for information about the built-in `PIPESTATUS` array in Bash.  If you only need to know if *some* process exited with non-zero status then you don't need to use the `pipestatus` variable in your code.

The code outputs:

```
declare -- status="1"
declare -a pipestatus=([0]="0" [1]="0" [2]="1" [3]="0" [4]="0")
```

The `status` value shows that one process exited with status 1.  The `pipestatus` value shows the exit status for each of the 5 processes in the pipeline.